# WooCommerce - Empty cart, first product doesnt being added with AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce, cart

Im using a wordpress + woocommerce website.

I'm building a custom page template with WP Bakery, desplaying:
[ cart | products table ] <<--- as layout.

The cart is added using W/C shortcode text for cart.
When the cart is empty, and im adding the first product (w/ ajax), the cart doesnt update and stays empty:

[image: empty cart after adding one product]

But then, when i hit refresh, the product appears, and then when i add another product, it is added with AJAX successfully.

[image]

How can i solve this and have the first product added with ajax successfully?

my website is:
https://shop.ganyavnez.co.il/test-2

Using latest W/C and Wordpress.
Plugins: W/C product Tables.

Comment: Check in your ajax function before adding the item that the cart exists, this may be due to WooCommerce now managing the sessions in the database and not in the `$_SESSION` variable.

Comment: Im not so experienced with code, ill be glad to know what to do :)